# Is there a comment character for iCal files (.ics)

Tags: icalendar, comments

I looked through the [iCal spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) and wasn't able to find anything at all. I've searched via Google quite a few times over the past few days as well.

I've found a few people that are using a server-side language (mostly PHP) to read an .ics and remove extra characters, so this leads me to believe they are not supported because they're removing extra markup.

Is it possible to include comments in an .ics file? I'm not talking about the Component Property.

**EDIT**: After more searching, I've come to the conclusion that anything outside the `BEGIN:VCALENDAR` and `END:VCALENDAR` might be ignored, thus making it a comment. I exported one of my Google Calendars, made some additions by hand, and uploaded it back with no apparent issues. Any thoughts or experiences on this idea?

**EDIT 2**: Returning to this much much later. I believe the best route would be to define your own custom property starting with X- as somewhat suggested below. If the tool reading the file does not recognize it, it will be ignored. So the specific approach would be to make sure you pick a name that is not likely to be recognized.

Comment: Your idea of putting content after the `END:VCALENDAR` line works for the iCalcreator PHP library. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: works for me. It does not produce errors with google calendar nor does it appear to affect the entry.

Comment: When adding such comments, loading the file into an application (local or web) and exporting the file again, will the comments still be there?

Answer (score 5):

you could add a x-comment property and have its value being your comment

Answer (score 1):

type 'X-' in front of any line

example: X-STATUS:CONFIRMED
,now the status:confirmed will be commented